# How to avoid UAC in second run of program?

Tags: c#, warnings, uac

I've written a C# application which adds to autorun on first launch.

But I have a problem: when autorun starts the program, UAC displays a warning like this:

[image]
<sub>(source: [micp.ru](http://s3.micp.ru/1RwD6.png))</sub>

How can I prevent this?

Comment: How is the program installed? msi? extracting zip file?

Comment: It's a single EXE file. Without installation

Comment: Then I'm fairly sure the only way to get rid of the message is to uncheck the checkbox or get a code signing certificate as @michaelb958 notes below. When a browser downloads an unsigned exe, it's set as untrusted by default, and the user has to explicitly choose to trust it.

Answer (score 3):

That's not UAC, that's the "oh noes teh internetz are full of virusez" warning, which is displayed on programs from the internet, and on programs that... well, even I don't understand some of the criteria. (I've run into it a few times while writing batch files on my computer.) Try unchecking the checkbox - that should banish the message. (If there's no checkbox, you're stuck with the message.)

Comment: I not want to disable this warning on my computer, i want preventing it from appearing in other people using my program

Comment: You'll have to sign the executable or something (I don't quite understand the process). Or just tell people to uncheck the checkbox.